# How to add constraint for 2 fields not having the same value?

Tags: django

How to write a check that checks if two objects of the same model are not the same object?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    first = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='first')
    second = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='second')

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(name='not_same', check=(first!=second))
        ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [**`F`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) to refer to a field, so:

```
from django.db.models import F, Q

class Foo(models.Model):
    first = models.ForeignKey(
        Bar,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='first'
    )
    second = models.ForeignKey(
        Bar,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='second'
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(name='not_same', check=~Q(first=F('second')))
        ]
```

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `Bar` model to the `Foo`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`first`</s> relation to `foo_first`.